# A few questions regarding importing a manually created data entity

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations, d3fo, data-entities

I used the data entity creation wizard and selected Reqplan table as the main data source, then I manually added ReqPlanVersion, ReqPO, ReqTrans table as additional data sources and created the relationships below.
[image]

As for the data entities fields I manually dragged a subsets of fields from the three manually added tables.

However when I try to import the data and add file, I receive the following issue:
[image]

Q1. In the past for some other entities I have changed ‘Allow Edit on Create’ from ‘Auto’ to ‘YES’ on these fields and it has worked but I am not sure if it’s the only way or is it following best practice? Also what is the determining factor for a field to be editable or not during import since they are all on AUTO?

When I try to map source to staging manually by drawing the mapping lines I get below issue:

[image]

Q2. What is going on with the configuration key? Is it because I manually dragged the fields from the additional data sources but not using the data entity creation wizard?

Lastly I been getting below issue:
[image]

Q3: Is there a way to find out which unique key it is referring to? Is it talking about the EntityKey in my Data Entity or Indexes in staging table? In either case there are more than one so I am not sure what it is referring to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Response from the community forum:

1) Check allowEdit property on table itself, so if it is "No" there then auto means "No". If you want to update them through data entity you will have to force them to "Yes"

2) It's not connected to manual addition, it just says that tables used in the entity has configuration key disabled, so you cannot export or import data into them, however, these tables could be added by wizard or manually, it does not matter. Also, Configuration key could be on fields as well or on EDT that these fields use, check them as well.

3) Entity has Key node and there and there you have key generated by wizard for you. It is used by framework to understand if record should be updated or created, if it does not work for you, change it on the data entity and regenerate staging. You need to refresh staging because error you get is SQL error, at this stage SSIS transfers data from a file into a staging table and data could not be copied because of index vialotion, so check staging table index and see if your file has any duplicates.